# MS Excel copy integers on same spreadsheet

Tags: excel, concatenation, formula

I have integers that are copied into an excel spreadsheet:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

With some formula, I'd like those to be copied to somewhere else on the same
excel sheet. =a1:a10 doesn't do anything helpful and only reports one of the values, just the a1 field.

What's the trick to have the data copied to a different set of fields?

I've tried =text(a1:a10), =CONCATENATE(a1:a10), rows, columns

So point and laugh at me, but PLEASE tell me what's the simple trick to duplicate data on the same exact spreadsheet!

edit...
This will work if I do =e4 in one cell followed by =e5, =e6 all in their own cells, but I still need to have commas between each value. For example:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

As you see below, the CONCATENATE worked for me.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to just enter, like, =A1, and then drag the mouse down from the right-hand corner.  You can turn on the RC style formulas to understand what this is doing

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I also needed a comma between each entry. I figured out how the concatenate works and will use that.

Works for me:

```
=CONCATANATE(A1,",",A2,",",A3,",",A4,",",A5,",",A6,",",A7,",",A8)
```

Result:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Comment: If you have the latest office 365 you can use `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:A8)`

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I have MS Office professional plus 2013. Know any neat tricks to work with it?

Comment: That is exactly what excel is not good at (join arrays)... but I'm confused: your own answer doesn't match your question...

Comment: There is a good concatenation function here which you can use http://www.cpearson.com/excel/stringconcatenation.aspx